# Error creating DB instance: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid DB engine for PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a PostgreSQL RDS instance using Terraform.
Here is how my configuration looks:

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "postgres" {
   name = "postgres-subnets"
   subnet_ids = ["mysub1","mysub2"]
}    
resource "aws_db_instance" "myrds" {
   engine = "postgresql"
   engine_version = "12.4"
   instance_class = "db.t2.micro"
   identifier = "myrds"
   username = "myuser"
   password = "*******"
   allocated_storage = 10
   storage_type = "gp2"
   db_subnet_group_name = "${aws_db_subnet_group.postgres.id}"
}
```

It fails with following error:

```
Error: Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid DB engine
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Terraform documentation needs to add the engine names which are supported:
`engine = "postgresql"` is incorrect. Supported value is `"postgres"`